"Git from Version Control" in android studio not showing my teams repositories/projects
I just installed Android Studio on new machine and logedin in the git from version control its showing all my personal repositories and not showing my teams related repositories...

Git from version controll showing all repositorys on my previous machine...
I try to direct clone repo with URL... and its again send me to login page of Github ... after clicking Authorize in Github ... its startes clone and show error Clone fail repository "something.git" not found
similar question
